# Good resources for soccer statistics, news, etc?

Tags: football, betting

I recently got $200 on a sports betting website as a gift from a friend, they have different sports but I am most interested in soccer. I have 0 experience in betting, and I also don't know much about soccer (I mean I understand the sport well but I don't watch matches or follow any team).

I was wondering if someone knows of some websites that provide useful information for betting, like past matches results, which players played that match, news, predictions, etc. (for free)

---

I'm editing the question because I can't comment. @Michael Myers: this question is about resources, but sport resources. It's the only stackexchange site I though the question would fit in. I can see other questions here that doesn't seem to be 100% about sports, there's a question about a gun leaking gas, my question is more related to sports than that. But if you think the question should be deleted, then I apologize. Thanks anyway.

Comment: While we do take questions about betting, this question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for resources, not a specific question.

Comment: Mark: You **can** comment on your *own* questions and answers or on answers on your questions.

Comment: I think the problem here is that the question is totally broad. There could be thousand of resources, and all be correct. So who will have a correct question? sound like a poll..