# League Wide Queryable Databases

Tags: statistics

Are there league wide queryable databases for any type of statistics for sports leagues? Does someone run them for MLB, NFL, NHL, NBA, BPL, la Liga etc.?

Are they SQL queryable?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is a [source/research request](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Here are other examples of [resource requests](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/218) asked here: https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3545/good-resources-for-soccer-statistics-news-etc https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2910/which-are-good-websites-to-follow-changes-in-atp-and-wta-ranking

Comment: Thanks. Here are databases for MLB stats: http://www.seanlahman.com/baseball-archive/statistics/